# Write and run pyspark in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: python, intellij-idea, apache-spark, pyspark

i am trying to work with Pyspark in IntelliJ but i cannot figure out how to correctly install it/setup the project. I can work with Python in IntelliJ and I can use the pyspark shell but I cannot tell IntelliJ how to find the Spark files (import pyspark results in "ImportError: No module named pyspark").

Any tipps on how to include/import spark so that IntelliJ can work with it are appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I tried this piece of code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
spark_conf = SparkConf().setAppName("scavenge some logs")
spark_context = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)
address = "C:\test.txt"
log = spark_context.textFile(address)

my_result = log.filter(lambda x: 'foo' in x).saveAsTextFile('C:\my_result')
```

with the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/U546816/IdeaProjects/sparktestC/.idea/sparktestfile", line 2, in <module>
spark_conf = SparkConf().setAppName("scavenge some logs")
File "C:\Users\U546816\Documents\Spark\lib\spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar\pyspark\conf.py", line 97, in __init__
File "C:\Users\U546816\Documents\Spark\lib\spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar\pyspark\context.py", line 221, in _ensure_initialized
File "C:\Users\U546816\Documents\Spark\lib\spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 35, in launch_gateway

File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__
return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the env path for (`SPARK_HOME` and `PYTHONPATH`) in your program run/debug 
configuration.

For instance:

```
SPARK_HOME=/Users/<username>/javalibs/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/
PYTHON_PATH=/Users/<username>/javalibs/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark
```

See attached snapshot in IntelliJ Idea

[image: Run/Debug configuration for PySpark]

Comment: The variables are PYTHONPATH and SPARK_HOME, for those of us behind tyrannical firewalls.

Comment: And the SPARK_HOME should include path untill the directory containing bin, python etc. and not until python.

Answer (score 1):

For example, something of this kind:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
spark_conf = SparkConf().setAppName("scavenge some logs")
spark_context = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)
address = "/path/to/the/log/on/hdfs/*.gz"
log = spark_context.textFile(address)

my_result = (log.

...here go your actions and transformations...

).saveAsTextFile('my_result')
```

Answer (score 0):

1 problem I encountered was space as in 'Program Files\spark' for environment variables SPARK_HOME and PYTHONPATH (as stated above) so I moved spark binaries to my user directory instead. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742703/spark-on-windows-10-files-spark-bin-jars-is-not-recognized-as-an-intern) answer.
Also, make sure you installed the packages for the environment.
Ensure you see pyspark package in Project Structure -> Platform Settings SDK -> Python SDK (of choice) -> Packages.
[image: pyspark Package]