# Spark on Windows 10. 'Files\Spark\bin\..\jars""\' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, windows, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am very frustrated by Spark. An evening wasted thinking that I was doing something wrong but I have uninstalled and reinstalled several times, following multiple guides that all indicate a very similar path.

On cmd prompt, I am trying to run:

```
pyspark
```

or

```
spark-shell
```

The steps I followed include downloading a pre-built package from:

https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

including spark 2.0.2 with hadoop 2.3 and spark 2.1.0 with hadoop 2.7.

Neither work and I get this error:

```
'Files\Spark\bin\..\jars""\' is not recognized as an internal or external  command,
operable program or batch file.
Failed to find Spark jars directory.
You need to build Spark before running this program.
```

I've setup my environment variables fine as well utilising the winutils.exe trick but these seem unrelated to the problem at hand.

I can't be the only one who's stuck on this problem. Anyone know a work around for getting this program to work in windows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've just found an answer in one of the answers to this question:

[Why does spark-submit and spark-shell fail with "Failed to find Spark assembly JAR. You need to build Spark before running this program."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618843/why-does-spark-submit-and-spark-shell-fail-with-failed-to-find-spark-assembly-j)

The following answer worked for me and is totally counter-intuitive:

"On Windows, I found that if it is installed in a directory that has a space in the path (C:\Program Files\Spark) the installation will fail. Move it to the root or another directory with no spaces."

Comment: I like your answer but after running the command ".\bin\sparkR" I've got a message "R is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Did you get the same warning?

Comment: I didn't see this but the first thing that springs to mind is that the environment variables may not be set up right.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by your environment variable settings, in fact you probably put the SPARK_HOME value as 'Program Files\Spark\bin", which has 2 issue :

- you have to remove the bin, spark home is just 'Program Files\Spark\'
- since the path to spark home contains a white space, it causes a problem therefore you can set it as 'Progra~1\Spark\'

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue. The main reason for this issue is the space in the folder path.
C:\Program Files\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7 for SPARK_HOME. Just move this spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7 folder to the root directory of C drive i.e C:\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7 and point the SPARK_HOME also to the same location. It solves the issue.